# How to fetch default value from an input into a servlet?

Tags: java, html, validation, servlets, input

I have an input type which has a default value. I want to fetch its value inside of a servlet. So, which method will work in this case?

I tried using `request.getParameter("FLC1")`, but that didn't work as well.

Following is the input code:-

```
<input type="text" name="FLC1" id="FLC1" value="Floral Lavender Candle" disabled>
```

Thank you

Comment: is because browser does not submit the disabled inputs.

Comment: instead of disabled make it readonly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your input element has a disabled attribute so it will not be submitted on form submit, instead make it a readonly and it should work.

```
<input type="text" name="FLC1" id="FLC1" value="Floral Lavender Candle" readonly>
```

Alternatively you can put a hidden filed in the form with same name attribute.

```
<input type="hidden" name="FLC1" value="Floral Lavender Candle">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can:

- Make the value server side an populate it in the jsp using el:

  value="${myvariable}"
- Store the value in a hidden field, it will be accessible then